# How to fix search returning hits for missing data in Liferay?

Tags: java, liferay

In Liferay we are looking for articles that satisfy certain conditions by using the following code:

```java
Hits hits = indexSearcherHelper.search(searchContext, query);
```

Search query which we use is defined as:

```java
BooleanFilter filter = new BooleanFilter();
filter.addRequiredTerm(Field.GROUP_ID, globalSiteId);
filter.addRequiredTerm(Field.STATUS, WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED);
filter.addRequiredTerm("ddmStructureKey", "TEST");
filter.addRequiredTerm("head", true);
MatchAllQuery query = new MatchAllQuery();
query.setPreBooleanFilter(filter);
```

and this search finds multiple hits.
Then we attempt to get the article like this:

```java
JournalArticleResource journalArticleResource = journalArticleResourceLocalService.getArticleResource(GetterUtil.getLong(hits.toList().get(0).get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK)));
JournalArticle article = journalArticleLocalService.getArticle(journalArticleResource.getGroupId(), journalArticleResource.getArticleId());
```

However, this produces following error:

> No JournalArticleResource exists with the primary key 809477.

In 95% of cases, this code works as expected. But in some cases (on some environments), it appears that index search found results which are not valid. Why does this happen?

Can it be that index has some stale records that are from old, already deleted articles? Do we need to reindex the database?

**UPDATE 1**: I have observed a very strange behaviour of the index search:

The following code:

```java
        for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println(counter);
System.out.println(indexSearcherHelper.search(searchContext, query).toList().size());
        }
```

produces this result:

```
0
0
1
4
2
7
3
0
4
4
5
7
6
0
7
4
8
7
9
0
```

There is only 1 result in reality that needs to be found. On all other environments this code keeps finding just one result in all 10 searches, since we added only 1 article.

In this case, however, it keeps finding no results, 4 results, 7 results and keeps repeating the same pattern.

What is going on here? Is database corrupted? Is it Liferay bug? How can the same search return different number of results?
(By the way, last year we did a live database migration from one server to another, that is, migration of the database while Liferay was up and running [not too good idea] to reduce the production downtime, so I am afraid that we might be experiencing the database corruption here.)

**UPDATE 2**: as requested in the comments, here is the version of the Liferay that we are using and an example of the search with values of some fields modified since this is a production example from closed source application.

Version:

- Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.0.4 GA5 (Wilberforce / Build 7004 / October 23, 2017)

```java
System.out.println(hits.toList().get(0));
```

```
{
    ddmTemplateKey=[673861],
    entryClassPK=[809477],
    ddm__keyword__673858__LActive_hr_HR=[true],
    publishDate=[20211116063000],
    ddm__keyword__673858__SActive_hr_HR=[false],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GNA_en_US_String_sortable=[ne],
    ddm__text__673858__OList_hr_HR_String_sortable=[32554651079], 
    classNameId=[0],
    ddm__keyword__673858__SActive_en_US_String_sortable=[false],
    ddm__keyword__673858__O_hr_HR_String_sortable=[opis pop upa],
    modified_sortable=[1637050218921],
    title_hr_HR=[Test ss n],
    ddm__keyword__673858__O_en_US=[Opis pop upa],
    version=[2.4],
    ddm__keyword__673858__B_en_US=[grey],
    ddm__keyword__673858__SActive_hr_HR_String_sortable=[false],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OAll_en_US_String_sortable=[false],
    status=[0],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GPA_en_US=[OK],
    publishDate_sortable=[1637044200000],
    content_hr_HR=[OK 32554651079 NE true Opis pop upa all true  Test pop najnoviji Utorak grey false all false /ervices],
    ddm__keyword__673858__TR_en_US=[all],
    ddm__keyword__673858__B_hr_HR=[grey],
    uid=[com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle_PORTLET_811280],
    localized_title_en_US_sortable=[test ss n],
    layoutUuid=[],
    ddm__text__673858__OList_en_US=[32554651079],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GNA_hr_HR=[NE],
    ddm__keyword__673858__TR_en_US_String_sortable=[all],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GNA_hr_HR_String_sortable=[ne],
    createDate=[20211115132217],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OAll_hr_HR_String_sortable=[false],
    displayDate_sortable=[1637044200000],
    ddm__keyword__673858__O_en_US_String_sortable=[opis pop upa],
    entryClassName=[com.liferay.journal.model.JournalArticle],
    ddm__keyword__673858__N_en_US=[Test pop najnoviji Utorak],
    ddm__keyword__673858__S_hr_HR_String_sortable=[all],
    userId=[30588],
    localized_title_en_US=[test ss n],
    ddm__keyword__673858__N_hr_HR_String_sortable=[test pop najnoviji utorak],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OListActive_hr_HR=[true],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GPA_hr_HR_String_sortable [ok],
    treePath=[, 673853],
    ddm__keyword__673858__B_en_US_String_sortable=[grey],
    ddm__keyword__673858__S_hr_HR=[all], groupId=[20152],
    ddm__keyword__673858__B_hr_HR_String_sortable=[grey],
    createDate_sortable=[1636982537964],
    classPK=[0],
    ddm__keyword__673858__S_en_US_String_sortable=[all],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GPA_hr_HR=[OK],
    scopeGroupId=[20152],
    articleId_String_sortable=[809475],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OAll_hr_HR=[false],
    modified=[20211116081018],
    ddm__keyword__673858__LActive_hr_HR_String_sortable=[true],
    ddm__keyword__673858__L_hr_HR=[/ervices],
    localized_title_hr_HR_sortable=[test ss n],
    ddm__keyword__673858__L_en_US=[/ervices],
    visible=[true],
    ddmStructureKey=[TEST],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OAll_en_US=[false],
    defaultLanguageId=[hr_HR],
    ddm__keyword__673858__L_hr_HR_String_sortable=[/ervices],
    viewCount_sortable=[0],
    folderId=[673853],
    classTypeId=[673858],
    ddm__text__673858__OList_hr_HR=[32554651079],
    ddm__keyword__673858__TR_hr_HR_String_sortable=[all],
    companyId=[20116],
    rootEntryClassPK=[809477],
    ddm__keyword__673858__LA_en_US_String_sortable=[true],
    displayDate=[20211116063000],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OListActive_hr_HR_String_sortable=[true],
    ddm__keyword__673858__SActive_en_US=[false],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OListActive_en_US=[true],
    ddm__keyword__673858__LActive_en_US=[true],
    content=[OK 32554651079 NE true Opis pop upa all true  Test pop najnoviji Utorak grey false all false /ervices],
    head=[true],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GPA_en_US_String_sortable=[ok],
    ddm__keyword__673858__OListActive_en_US_String_sortable=[true],
    ratings=[0.0],
    expirationDate_sortable=[9223372036854775807],
    viewCount=[0],
    ddm__text__673858__OList_en_US_String_sortable=[32554651079],
    localized_title_hr_HR=[test ss n],
    expirationDate=[99950812133000], 
    ddm__keyword__673858__N_en_US_String_sortable=[test pop najnoviji utorak],
    roleId=[20123, 20124, 20126],
    ddm__keyword__673858__S_en_US=[all],
    articleId=[809475],
    ddm__keyword__673858__N_hr_HR=[Test pop najnoviji Utorak],
    userName=[tuser%40admin -],
    localized_title=[test ss n],
    stagingGroup=[false],
    headListable=[true],
    ddm__keyword__673858__L_en_US_String_sortable=[/ervices],
    ddm__keyword__673858__O_hr_HR=[Opis pop upa],
    ddm__keyword__673858__TR_hr_HR=[all],
    ddm__keyword__673858__GNA_en_US=[NE]
}
```

Comment: Which Liferay version are you using?

Comment: We are using the Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.0.4 GA5 (Wilberforce / Build 7004 / October 23, 2017).

Comment: Do you have an example of an invalid result?

Comment: It took me some while to get it, since this is from production environment, but please take a look at UPDATE 1 and 2 in my post.

Answer (score 2):

You might be using the wrong service, try using the `journalArticleLocalService`.

The id of the journal article resource is the id of the journal article plus 1, so if you have more than one article, in most cases it wont produce the error, but will return the wrong article.

Comment: What I ommited in my post is the next line of code since it is past the point where exception is thrown, but actually, we are retrieveing the article like this: ```JournalArticleResource journalArticleResource = journalArticleResourceLocalService.getArticleResource(GetterUtil.getLong(hits.toList().get(0).get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK)));``` ```JournalArticle article = journalArticleLocalService.getArticle(journalArticleResource.getGroupId(), journalArticleResource.getArticleId());
``` Is this ok way?

Comment: I don't think so, probably the id that returns from the search is the journalArticle id, not the journalArticleResource id, would have to check your search. Try to use just the `journalArticleLocalService` passing it the `GetterUtil.getLong(hits.toList().get(0).get(Field.ENTRY_CLASS_PK))`

Comment: Can you use the debug mode and post what is inside one of the hits?

Comment: Yes, I updated my post with the data. See UPDATE 1 and 2 for details and additional clues.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are hitting some inconsistencies in your Elasticsearch index: JournalArticles that don't exist in the Database but they exist in the Elasticsearch.

You can double check this and correct it using my Liferay Index Checker, see https://github.com/jorgediaz-lr/index-checker#readme

Once you have installed it, you have to:

1. Check the "Display orphan index entries" option
2. Click on "Check Index"
3. If you have any orphan results, you can remove them clicking on the "Remove orphans" button.